# ASP.NET Core Deployment & Migration

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, identityserver4, ef-core-2.1

over the last three month i developed a complex web application using **ASP.NET Core 2.1**, **EF Core 2.1**, **IdentityServer4 2**.

My application consists of three individual web apps: the sts project, the data api and the mvc frontend. For storing data there are two databases: **identity-db** (for storing users, relationships, configuration, ...) and **data-db**. Both of them use the code first approach with ef migrations.

Now the question:
*How do i deploy (manually or automatic) this project to an
Windows Server with IIS installed? The iis website must be
configured to run under a single domain with no sub domains.*

Additional information: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, an selfhosted GitLab (Free) with a Windows Server 2016 as build machine. I don't really use the CI/CD features of GitLab because i just haven't the time to get really into this at all. As far as i know docker could also be an option.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's 3 question in one, you ask should 3 differents questions

Comment: @aguafrommars Thanks for your advice. I removed the second and third question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

As this is a very general question I am going to give a very general answer.

Install IIS in the windows server you of your choice or if you already have it continue to next step.

Install needed modules via Roles and Features (make sure you install also your dependencies, like .Net 4.7 or whatever).

Create a website and specify a folder for the content (ideally on a different drive than the system drive). (This can be done with a right-click inside IIS > Sites folder for example)

Deploy your application or site in the content folder. Basically copy the files and folders to the specified folder.

Proceed to configure the AppPool, the user that runs the appPool, the bindings (basically hostname and port but also if needed, https binding and certificate).

Configure authentication and authorization. Basically choose Windows auth if people in your network will log on the application with their usual AD account. Otherwise you can go for anonimous for example. If you want to restrict access to certain AD groups or users do it with Authorization rules.

Make sure the user that runs the application pool has permissions on the content folder, if using windows auth also Machine Users need permissions there (at least read). Also check if you need IIS_IUSRS permission on the folder (if running the pool with AppPoolIdentity)

try the site and see if it throws any HTTP status code and continue from there.

Do the same with the other 2 sites.

If any app has a connectionm string you will need the corresponding DB driver on the server. Troubleshooting DB connectivity is basically telnet and FW rules after driver and connection string is setup.

You might want to "convert to application" in IIS but that is your choice and AFAIK depends on the code.

That is basically it, I know its not very precise but at least you have some hints.

Comment: A couple things missing:  If you need access to a DB you need to add the AppPool as a user to the DB.  With the exact username of `IIS APPPOOL\<name>` Searching for an AD object will not work, and you will not find it in the object browser.  Secondly, if you want to be able to 'publish to IIS' using WebDeploy, you must download WebDeploy from the WMI Installer (you also may need to add the windows feature WMI Installer)

Comment: This will get you easy manual publishing.  If you want automatic publishing, you're going to run into a lot more overhead and you would be better off making a CI/CD pipeline in Azure.